# prawn repeat template filling it with different content

Tags: templates, repeat, prawn

I have a 4-page template for my PDF I would like to generate with [prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/). I need to repeat this template in my pdf a number of times each time filling it with different content.

If I use:

```rb
  Prawn::Document.generate('output.pdf', template: "a_template.pdf")
```

I get the template once in the output.pdf, subsequent pages are empty.

If I use

```rb
  ["John", "Jane"].each do |user|
    start_new_page template: 'a_template.pdf', page: 1
    text "Content filled on page 1 for user #{user}"
    3.times { |i| start_new_page template: 'a_template.pdf', template_page: i+2 }
  end
```

I get the text "Content filled on page 1 for user..." repeated and overwriting one another, on every page that is the first page from the template. So for every fourth page I have content for all users rendered in the same place on the page.

Does anybody knows how to make prawn include a template a number of times, every time filling the template with different contents? I would like to avoid generating a bunch of PDF files and concatenating them together...

Even if I first concatenate together template required number of times, for each user using code below:

```rb
tmp_template = Tempfile.new ['template', '.pdf'], tmpdir

Prawn::Document.generate(tmp_template.path, skip_page_creation: true) do
  users.each do |u|
    4.times { |i| start_new_page template: card_tmpl, template_page: i+1 }
  end
end
```

And then do:

```rb
Prawn::Document.generate('output.pdf', template: tmp_template.path)
```

to fill subsequent template copies for subsequent users, it still puts the same content whenever the copy of the first page appears in the new template!

Answer (score 2):

No other appeared, so I did the following thing.

First create new PDF object without any pages:

```rb
pdf = Prawn::Document.new skip_page_creation: true
```

Then for each user:

1. Create a new, complete PDF filling required template and save it to temporary file `tempfile` (using [Tempfile](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html)).
2. Include this temporary file in the PDF created at the beginning (the `pdf` object) like this (assuming that the template has two pages):

```rb
      2.times { |i| pdf.start_new_page template: tempfile, template_page: i+1 }
```

Finally, render the final PDF:

```rb
pdf.render 'output.pdf'
```

Performance is awful. But it works and PDF generated this way opens with acrobat reader.

Comment: Prawn maintainer's comments to [this issue](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/494) indicate that we should rather find another pdf library. Prawn decided to drop support for templates.